# Git hooks not generated

Tags: githooks, husky

I am working on a project that has some git hooks setup using `husky`. I ran `npm install` and I can see that husky is installed but the hooks are not generated.

How can I generate the same?

PS I do not have any pre-existing hooks.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually trigger hook generation by using
`node node_modules/husky/husky.js install`
or
`node node_modules/husky/bin/install.js` for some older versions.
Ref: https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/81